# Recommend an Appropriate Object-Orientated Design Pattern To Replace This Code

Tags: .net, design-patterns, oop

I have a menu click event that looks something like this....

```
Public Sub ToolbarManager_ToolClick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Case "New"
        CreateNewFile()
    Case "Save"
        SaveCurrentFile()
    Case "Exit"
        ExitApp()
    Case.......
    etc...
    etc...
End Sub
```

This strikes me as being 'ugly' - but I'm unsure of the 'best' way or the most appropriate way to clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design pattern

Answer (score 2):

If the switch case is just in one place, I'd bite my lip and live with it.

If it's mushrooming everywhere, I'd try to use [Replace conditional with polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)